# Custom TypeScript definitions file not picked up by compiler?

Tags: typescript, jquery-tools

I'd like to use the [Scrollable UI tool](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html) from the jQuery Tools library in my web application, which is using TypeScript. As there is unfortunately no corresponding definitions file on the [DefinitelyTyped GitHub repository](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped), I've created my own:

```
/// <reference path="./jquery-1.8.d.ts"/>

declare module JQueryTools {

    interface ScrollableOptions {
        clonedClass?: string;
        disabledClass?: string;
        easing?: string;
        items?: string;
        keyboard?: any; // boolean or string
        circular?: any // boolean
        next?: string;
        prev?: string;
        speed?: number;
        vertical?: any; // boolean
    }

    interface ScrollableUIParams {

    }

    interface ScrollableEvent {
        (event: Event, ui: ScrollableUIParams): void;
    }

    interface ScrollableEvents {
        onBeforeSeek?: ScrollableEvent;
        onSeek?: ScrollableEvent;
        onAddItem?: ScrollableEvent;
    }

    interface Scrollable extends ScrollableOptions, ScrollableEvents {
    }
}

interface JQuery {
    scrollable(): JQuery;
    scrollable(methodName: string): JQuery;
    scrollable(options: JQueryTools.ScrollableOptions): JQuery;
    scrollable(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string): any;
    scrollable(optionLiteral: string, options: JQueryTools.ScrollableOptions): any;
    scrollable(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;
}
```

In my .ts file, I have the following call:

```
$(".scrollableWrapper").scrollable({vertical: true});
```

On compile, I get the following error:

```
error TS2094: The property 'scrollable' does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'.
```

If I cut all the code out of my definitions file and paste it into the the jquery-1.8.d.ts file, everything appears to work fine with no compile errors. My question, then, is: why is my custom-made d.ts file not being picked up by the typescript compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition looked okay to me, so I grabbed the jQuery.d.ts from Definitely Typed and added your code to scrollable.d.ts and it all worked fine... as long as I referenced your definitions...

```
/// <reference path="scrollable.d.ts" />

$('#id').scrollable({ vertical: true });
```

This made me think that maybe you hadn't referenced your definition file (I called it scrollable.d.ts, but you might have called it jquery.scrollable.d.ts or something like that).

Comment: This did the trick; I had forgotten to open up the main TypeScript file and add the reference path to the big list of references in there. I added the reference path in and now everything is working as expected. Thanks!